# Bootstrap JS - Remove margin gap between checkbox control group label and checkbox controls

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I reduce the gap between the label and the check-boxes group. I can see that first checkbox get a `margin-top:10px` but I don't know hot to tackle it elegantly or better say staying in bootstrap realm.[JSFiddle - Link](https://jsfiddle.net/py1rasge/1/)

Please note in future I will adding check-boxes dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `.checkbox` class and remove the top margin like this :

```
.checkbox{
  margin-top:0px;
}
```

You can find a working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gurtejsingh/py1rasge/4/

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone else is looking for a cleaner solution, Bootstrap provides a separate `.checkbox-inline` class that removes the margins entirely.

It's designed for inline checkboxes so you would have to move your class definition down to the labels in order for all the checkboxes to not appear inline.

[Here's how it looks in action.](https://jsfiddle.net/xw0z3jug/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this style

```
label {
    margin-left: <any negative value>
}
```